# Is there any way to bind shortcuts to buttons in Vue.js without plugins?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component, vuetify.js

So my question is about binding some keyboard shortcuts, for example `v-on:keyup.enter="someEvent()"` to buttons in the UI `<button :click="someEvent()">$t{{ nameOfBtn }}<button>`.
Perhaps there is a way to combine these two in one  tag.
I've been playing around with these two bindings but have not got any desirable result.

NB: I cannot use any plugins.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/events.html#Key-Modifiers

You can bind keyup handlers, but it might not make sense in a button. Presses in an input field are captured to the element but most others are global to the page. You could add a listener when your component is created though...

```js
{
  created: function () {
    window.addEventListener('keyup', this.previous)
  },
  methods: {
    previous: function (e) {
      // check key code
    }
  },
  beforeDestroy: function () {
    // remove listener
  }
}
```